# Some software runs only by root terminal

Tags: debian, sudo, root, gtk

I'm facing this odd situation here, programs such as `gparted`, `furiusisomount` and `Rstudio` never run by clicking on their icons in the applications menu or by running them with terminal as a normal user. But they would work only on sudo terminal.

I encounter following errors:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/furiusisomount/main.py", line 431, in <module>
    app = main_window(parameter)
  File "/usr/share/furiusisomount/main.py", line 51, in __init__
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 547, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

though rstudio never has any output.
I have no idea what's going on and I'm totally new to Linux and Debian wheezy.
P.S. This is the warning I faced from the R command only on terminal without sudo:

```
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C"
```

output of locale:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_GB.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.utf8
LC_TIME=en_US.utf8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.utf8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.utf8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `locale`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have no graphical tool installed which asks for your sudo or root password before running a tool which needs these permissions.

```
apt-get install gksu
```

should do the trick.

Comment: It is already installed